# not exiting out of "while" loop, but why?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

So I have here a program that simply mimics checkers (but instead of jumping, one piece simply "eats" another piece). I have a simple class that implements a "Checkers" class object and creates an int array variable called "chips" there is a "WHILE" statements that creates a loop while chip[0] and chips[1] integers are greater than 0. it looks like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){

        Checkers c = new Checkers();
        c.init();
        c.printBoard();
        int[] chips = c.count();
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(chips[0]>0 && chips[1]>0){
            System.out.println("\nYour move? 4 ints: src row, src col, dest row, dest col separated by [SPACE]");
            int srcR = kbd.nextInt();
            int srcC = kbd.nextInt();
            int destR = kbd.nextInt();
            int destC = kbd.nextInt();
            kbd.nextLine();
            c.move(srcR,srcC,destR,destC);
            c.printBoard();
            System.out.println(c.getMessage());
            c.count();
        }
    }
```

My count method in the Checkers class looks like this:

```
public int[] count() {  

    int wht=0;
    int blk=0;

    System.out.println();

    for(int i=0; i<board.length;i++)    {
        for(int z=0; z<board[0].length;z++)     {
            if(board[i][z] instanceof White)    {
                wht++;
            }
            else if(board[i][z] instanceof Black)   {
                blk++;
            }
        }
    }

    int[] arr = {wht,blk};  
    System.out.println("Whites: "+wht+"\nBlacks: "+blk);    


    return arr;   
}
```

The board is 8 x 8 (which is what board.length is), and the count method is simply to return the value of "arr" so that it can report back to "chips" to decide whether or not chips[1] and chips[0] are both greater than one (that they both have at least one White or Black pieces on the board.) the array is only supposed to consist of two values (ie. {white,black}; ) I've tried reformatting the entire count() in various ways, but this is only one of a few ways that the code compiles.

here is the output:

01234567

0|........

1|..B.....

2|........

3|........

4|........

5|..B.B.B.

6|.B.B.B.B

As you can see there are no White pieces any longer (supposed to be at the top). I would appreciate help considering this is probably an easy fix staring right under my nose but it is annoying, so I hope I explained this well enough. Thank you.

oh btw, I was told not to touch the main method at all.

Comment: i would say that your lector has an error in the main function, you should ask him :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are throwing away the chip count in your loop...
change the line:

```
c.count();
```

into:

```
chips = c.count();
```

Comment: That worked. I know it is a very easy fix, so thanks. Nonetheless, I was told not to touch the main method (the TestCheckers.java, which contains the c.count(); ). Is there a way that this could work when changing the count() method instead?

Comment: If you wanted to fix that, you would have to write into chips array. But the array is local only for the main function, I don't know how to change it from `count()` because it doesn't see the main function variables. The count function has its own local scope and its variables... you should definitely point out that there is probably that error in main().